# Does apache apex have some Web UI

Tags: apache-apex

I'm quite new to Apache Apex platform. Does it have some web ui? I was able to run docker sandbox and some example app. Nevertheless, yarn tracking url points to 404 pages. For example http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1527541640016_0001

> Sorry, got error 404

I already find out that there are some rest endpoints behind this proxy. Eg
http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1527541640016_0001/ws/v2/stram/logicalPlan

> {"operators":[{"name":"console","attributes": /.../

However, I wasn't able to find any human readable webui with app status. Does it exist?

Answer (score 2):

Earlier, DataTorrent (Creator of Apache apex) was offering web UI for managing your apache apex applications. This was proprietary software with free trial license. But, that software is discontinued.

As per my knowledge, as of now there is no webui software for apache apex which is actively maintained by some engineering team.

Some components are available here https://github.com/atrato. But, they are not full blown webui.